# Visual Studio Code doesn't see folders to open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I was trying to open folders from frontendmentor, but VSC doesn't see any of these saved on  my computer. I installed also VSC insiders and it was the same. I reinstalled and again, nothing. It's very annoying as I'm not able to practice some coding. I'll be appreciated if someone could help me.

Comment: Try running as administrator.

Comment: Didn't work out, I guess I'll try to install again windows and then see, if it's gonna work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So I simply forgot to extract files from zip folder and that was the reason why it didn't work